# Is there a way to point an ASP.NET app to references instead of copying them to the Bin folder?

Tags: asp.net, reference, web-config

We have a bunch of sample ASP.NET applications. I'd rather not copy the DLLs to the Bin folder in every sample because then all the files have to be updated on a change.

Is there a way to point the ASP.NET app at the references like can be done with a Forms or command line app?

**Update:** To answer the questions below let me explain a bit better what the situation is here. We have a commercial product that is a set of DLLs. We provide a number of sample applications using it, including several that are ASP.NET apps. All of this, our product DLLs and our sample source, is installed on a user's computer.

When they go to compile one of the samples we want that sample to use the version of the DLLs installed with it. The install process has place in GAC as the default option, but the user can uncheck that if they do not want the DLLs in the GAC and in that case we have to access the DLLs where they were installed, or copy them to each Bin directory.

Comment: Are you using source control?

Comment: Can you add the sample app in your solution? In this way, the newly added project will be given the reference to existing project(`Using Add project Reference`).

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand....Wouldn't that be the "desired" result -if the assemblies are updated/fixed shouldn't the app know about them? Are you referencing the dlls or the projects? If you want a "code freeze" then remove the sample project/s from the solution(?)

Answer (score 3):

To add reference right click on bin folder in visual studio and you will find add reference option there.

Answer (score 2):

The question is clear but the background is not.

It makes no sense to me to have a couple of applications which all use the same application dll. Is it just a library used by all applications?

There are some options depending on what you have and what you need:

**1. add reference directly**

If you really just want to add a reference, right-click on "references" in your VS project and select "add reference". Choose the reference an click ok. After that, right-click the added reference and select "properties" and set "local copy" to false, so it's not copied to the bin folder.

Maybe the option names are a bit different, but I don't have an english VS right now. Should be nearly what you have to do.

***EDIT***

In this window set "local copy" to "false" (here shown as "Lokale Kopie", sorry, it's german).

[image: set local copy]

**2. put dlls in GAC**

If you have a shared code library for a couple of applications on the same server you could think about putting that library into the [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx).

**3. problems with source control**

As mentioned from IrishChieftain you maybe use source control and don't want to update the dlls in the bin folder every time. The solution for that would be just ignoring the bin folder in your source control.

Comment: Hi; I'm not finding it. I can do Add Reference and it copies the DLL to my Bin directory. But a RMB does not give me a set local copy property. Not in the properties window either for it. Is there something else I need to do to get this option? thanks - dave

Comment: Hm, I don't know, it should be there. I added a picture of my property view (sorry, its german), what options do you have there?

Answer (score 1):

You could add any references you'd like using the context menu on the References node of your project:
[image]

In the 'Add Reference' dialog click on the Browse tab and you can browse to and add any outside references you need. For common assemblies we usually put them in a common location on the file system  and then reference them from that location whenever we need to.

Answer (score 1):

There are occasions where you will not want to reference certain assemblies at design-time.  There is an avenue for you to load them, based on logic, at run-time with the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event handler.  If you have assemblies that you can reference through a level of abstraction and that you do not want to reference directly you can use the following pattern to omit them and execute some algorithm at run-time to find and then add the assembly to the AppDomain.

This is a snippet that I put in the global.asax, Application_Start handler:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
    }

    System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        // use this space to add logic to find your assemblies

        return null; // will throw a Dependency-related exception
    }
```

Let me know if there are any questions or if I am missing the point of your question.

-G